# How to know "The DNS name of the remote host" of a computer?

Tags: c#

I have two programs use to communicate with each other via UDP protocol (client and server), but when the client connects to the server using the method Connect (
    string hostname,
    int port
), Nothing happened.
This is code:

```
                udpclient.Connect("asuspc",6500);
            string duongdan = tbduongdan.Text;
            Byte[] sendbyte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(duongdan);
            udpclient.Send(sendbyte, sendbyte.Length);
```

"asuspc" is name of computer that i intend to connect. 
After a while to find out, I know that the hostname is "The DNS name of the remote host" rather than the name of computer, then what is "The DNS name of the remote host"?How to know "The DNS name of the remote host" of a computer?

Comment: Are both computers on your LAN?

Comment: Yes. They are. Can you give me some suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, UDP is a connection-less protocol. You do not need to connect in order to send/receive data.

Note that calling `Connect()` on a `UdpClient` object [does *nothing* other than setting a *default* remote host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4w4cta7.aspx) so that you won't have to specify it each time you use the `Send` method. So don't expect anything to "happen" after the client calls the `Connect` method.

With that out of the way, if both your server and your client are on your private LAN, why don't you use the computer's IP? *e.g.*

```
// replace 192.168.1.44 with the server's private IP
udpclient.Connect("192.168.1.44",6500);
string duongdan = tbduongdan.Text;
Byte[] sendbyte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(duongdan);
udpclient.Send(sendbyte, sendbyte.Length);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer above! But if both my server and my client are not on my private LAN, so what can i do to make a connection between client and server?

Comment: @huyleuit, you're welcome. If your server is not on your LAN, then _if_ it has a publicly known hostname such as `meta.stackoverflow.com` you can use that instead. The hostname can be resolved by DNS servers to an IP address, which at the moment for `meta.stackoverflow.com` is `69.59.197.21`. So, as you can see, it will finally need an IP address to connect to anyway, so if you know your server's IP address, it would be easier to use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... I think that a bit of TCP/IP reading will help you a lot :-)

Every machine has an assigned IP address. To not have to remember those long IP addresses, DNS servers were created, so you can write "host.domain.com", and your DNS servers tells you that this "machine DNS name" corresponds with the IP address xx.xx.xx.xx.

Said that, to know the "DNS name" of a machine, under windows (and linux) you can write:

nslookup ip_address_of_the_machine

Example: nslookup 192.168.1.2

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a web site for programmers to ask questions related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

In server side, (code to get ip address only)

```
// get the ip and port number where the client will be listening on
static IPEndPoint GetClientInfo()
{
    // wait for client to send data
    using (UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(6500))
    {
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6500);
        byte[] receive_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

        return groupEP;
    }
}
```

Then to get IP

```
var ip = clientInfo.Address.ToString();
    var port = clientInfo.Port;

UdpClient client = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Any, 6500));
client.Connect(ip, port);  // use ip address
```

Then in client side you can recieve the data using the buffer